# Unable to push from and pull to git from [android studio]

Tags: android, git

Unable to pull from and push to git from the Android Studio -> git -> pull/push

Already tried uninstalling android studio completely form my windows 10 and reinstalling but of no use.

pulling changes from origin is being shown indefinitely [see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8Lzg.jpg)

hope someone will suggest me a good solution... thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

you probably introduced a wrong password. also had the same issue and what I did was to deleting all the git files generated when I did git add/commit. and repeated the connection process